# Saving a ZipFile to FileField in Django

Tags: django, zip, filefield

I have the following model in Django:

```
class AksOrder(models.Model):
    zip_file = models.FileField(upload_to='aks_zips/%M/%S/', blank=True)
```

and in my views I have in essential these functions:

```
def gen_zip(pk, name, vars):
    zipObj = ZipFile(os.path.join('/tmp/', str(name) + '_' + str(pk) + '.zip'), 'w')
    zipObj.write(pdf_files[0].path, '/filea.pdf')
    zipObj.write(pdf_files[1].path, '/fileb.pdf')

def aksorder_complete(request, pk):
    ao = get_object_or_404(AksOrder, id=pk)
    zipObj = generate_shop_zip(ao.c.pk, ao.dl, ao.vars)
    ao.zip_file.save('file.zip', zipObj)
```

I did not only try this version, but this one seems the most reasonable and logic one to me. I get a `There is no item named 65536 in the archive`. When I modify it slightly and close the file at the end of zip-writing in the first function, I get a `ValueError: Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed` message. Both times, the zip-File is generated properly in /tmp/ I could not work arount it. And that's only locally, I need to do it for S3 later...

Comment: You want to insert `images` in **Zipfile** ?

Comment: no, pdfs. as stated in line 3 and 4 from `gen_zip` function. It works. What I am asking basically is, how to save a zipflie to a `FileField` in django. I cannot make `Filefield = Zipfile`.

Answer (score 2):

I finally achieved it: I added a `zipObj.close()` to the first function at the end and I modified the 2nd function like so:

```
file = open('path/to/file.zip', 'rb')
ao.zip_file.save('name.zip', file)
```

apparently, the `rb` mode in file-open was decisive.